# prettier --check always fails when using VSCode prettier plugin if prettier --write has never been run when running linux project on windows

Tags: reactjs, terminal, prettier, windows-terminal, prettier-vscode

I have a very weird problem and I would be happy if anyone could (please) help :)

I have an NX project (created in a Linux env), and I'm now using it on windows.

My **VSCode** uses the latest prettier version -->>  `prettier v9.10.3`.

My (monorepo NX) **project** uses the latest prettier version -->> `prettier v2.8.1`.

My `.preetierrc` file is intentionally empty because my team uses the default prettier settings, and **all of my files have been formatted using prettier-vscode-plugin which is my default formatter.**

I did `git pull` and `npm i` and everything works perfectly.
When I run

```
prettier --check "apps\stt-monitor-front-end\src\app\components\CallCardsContainer.component.tsx"
```

on a specific file/folder it always fails with the

> Code style issues found in the above file. Forgot to run Prettier?

message, although I know for sure that the file/folder has been `prettier`ized in my VSCode.

** In fact, even If I **delete** the entire file's content and write const x = 5; with prettier plugin activated it still fails.

My main concern --->> `prettier --write` fixes the problem but it changes (not really) the entire file and it's like I created a new file, although everything is exactly the same!
Something is definitely wrong and I don't know how to fix it.

In addition, even if I do use `prettier --write` for the entire project my VSCode-prettier-plugin won't change any of the files because it works properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after hours of googling.

https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#end-of-line

The project was created on **Linux** and the “End of Line” style in Linux and Windows **looks the same** but it’s not the same.

I added:

```json
“endOfLine”: “auto”
```

to my `.prettierrc` file :)
And everything worked!